# How can I report on the name of an object with fluent assertions

Tags: c#, automated-tests, fluent-assertions

I have a test that checks several objects in a table on our website. The test is written in SpecFlow and C#

It looks something like this:

```
When I click proceed
Then I should see the following values
     | key       | value     |
     | tax       | 5.00      |
     | delivery  | 5.00      |
     | subtotal  | 20.00     |
```

My code behind for the "Then" step is something similar to:

```
[StepDefinition("I should see the following values")]
public void IShouldSeeTheFollowingValues(Table table)
{
    var basketSummary = new BasketModel();

    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
    {
        switch (row["key"])
        {
            case "tax":
                basketSummary.Tax.Should().Be(row["value"]);
                break;
            case "delivery":
                basketSummary.Delivery.Should().Be(row["value"]);
                break;
            case "subtotal":
                basketSummary.Subtotal.Should().Be(row["value"]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is in our build logs if the test errors it looks something like this:

```
When I click proceed
-> done: OrderConfirmationPageSteps.ClickProceed() (1.0s)
Then I should see the following values
  --- table step argument ---
     | key       | value     |
     | tax       | 5.00      |
     | delivery  | 5.00      |
     | subtotal  | 20.00     |
-> error: Expected value to be 5.00, but found 1.00.
```

as you can see above its hard to distinguish which object it means... when it says it expects it to be 5.00
Is there a way I can modify the output to say something along the lines of:

```
-> error: Expected value of Tax to be 5.00, but found 1.00.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:

1. Pass a reason phrase to the `Be()` method, e.g.
   `basketSummary.Delivery.Should().Be(row["value"], "because that's
   the tax value");
2. Wrap the call in an `AssertionScope` and pass the description (the context) into its constructor, like
   [this](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/blob/e240c8c8d02160fd69e22d7590901df429f86bd3/Tests/FluentAssertions.Shared.Specs/AssertionScopeSpecs.cs#L170)

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version https://fluentassertions.com/introduction#subject-identification

```
string username = "dennis";
username.Should().Be("jonas");
//will throw a test framework-specific exception with the following message:

Expected username to be "jonas" with a length of 5,
 but "dennis" has a length of 6, differs near "den" (index 0).
```

> Fluent Assertions can use the C# code of the unit test to extract the
> name of the subject and use that in the assertion failure.
>
> Since it needs the debug symbols for that, this will require you to
> compile the unit tests in debug mode, even on your build servers.